# jQuery .each loop one at a time

Tags: javascript, jquery, loops, each

I have an each loop, going through a specific class (.casebox). It checks for additional classes, and changes the title and loads specific content via .load().

**HTML**

```
<div id="mainbody">
 <div class="halfbox">
                    <h4 class="box casetitle"></h4>
                    <div class="caseloader loader"><img src="<?php echo $url_resources_images; ?>ajax-loader.gif" alt="Loading..." /><br /><p>Please be patient, loading cases...</p></div>
                    <div class="casebox dashbox"></div>
                </div>
                <div class="halfbox">
                    <h4 class="box casetitle"></h4>
                    <div class="caseloader loader"><img src="<?php echo $url_resources_images; ?>ajax-loader.gif" alt="Loading..." /><br /><p>Please be patient, loading cases...</p></div>
                    <div class="casebox dashbox apending"></div>
                </div>
```

**Javascript**

```
function loadCases(){
$(".casebox").each(function(){
    getURLs();
    boxType();
    console.log('activated');
    div = $(this).parents('div').eq(0);
    div.css('background', 'blue');

    //BOXOVERIDE - FOR WHEN THE URL CAN'T BE SET E.G. DASHBOARD
    if($(this).hasClass("allopen")){
        div.find($('.casetitle').text('All Open Cases'));
        caseGET = "&casetype=allopen";
    } else if($(this).hasClass("copen")){
        div.find($('.casetitle').text('My Created Cases (Open)'));
        caseGET = "&casetype=copen";
    } else if($(this).hasClass("aopen")){
        div.find($('.casetitle').text('My Assigned Cases (Open)'));
        caseGET = "&casetype=aopen";
    } else if($(this).hasClass("allclosed")){
        div.find($('.casetitle').text('All Closed Cases'));
        caseGET = "&casetype=allclosed";
    } else if($(this).hasClass("cclosed")){
        div.find($('.casetitle').text('My Created Cases (Closed)'));
        caseGET = "&casetype=cclosed";
    } else if($(this).hasClass("aclosed")){
        div.find($('.casetitle').text('My Assigned Cases (Closed)'));
        caseGET = "&casetype=aclosed";
    } else if($(this).hasClass("apending")){
        div.find($('.casetitle').text('My Assigned Cases (Pending Close)'));
        caseGET = "&casetype=apending";
    }
    console.log(caseGET);
    $(this).load("boxes/cases.php?boxtype=" + boxtype + caseGET + orgGET, function (){
        div.find(".caseloader").hide();
    });
});
}
```

However, it seems to run through quickly and when it gets onto the second loop, it appears to override settings made on the 1st run through. The 1st run has no matching result for .hasClass and its title is set by the function getURLS(). Yet when the second loop goes through, it overrides what was set in the 1st box, and puts the title as "My Assigned Cases (Pending Close)" even though it is only the 2nd box which has this class. On top of this, the 1st box loads the correct content, but the loading bar doesn't disappear, but the loading bar on the 2nd box does disappear.

Any ideas on how to ensure it sticks? This probably isnt very clear, but hopefully from the code above, it will help with the explanation. Thanks.

Comment: That code is pretty hard to read... Have you considered a dictionary lookup? You basically create an object with all the different cases and assign a function to each one, then lookup the current class against the dictionary. It will significantly improve your code readability, and probably size as well. Although in this case you can probably get away with just an object with classes as keys and text as values.

Comment: what do you mean by second loop? Also first `if` is trying to use `find` on a boolean.

Comment: Why are you calling `getURLs()` and `boxtype()` each time through the loop rather than once before the loop.

Comment: @elclanrs that is my plan, but needed to test it with multiple boxes on the same page with potentially different classes before I go and do that, as I have a few more to add yet.
charlietfl remove, wasn't meant to be there, bad copy/paste.

Comment: @jfriend00 as each box can be different, the 1st box gets its content by using a default, but the 2nd box has it manually set using a class.

Comment: @SeánMcCabe - maybe you need to show us what those functions do.  They don't take any arguments or return any values so how are they doing something different each time through the loop?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I'm not sure where boxType, orgGet are coming from... But i think the issue was that when you declared stuff like $('.casetitle'), it actually re-searches the whole document for those classes.

try something like:

```
function loadCases(){
    $(".casebox").each(function(){
        getURLs();
        boxType();
        console.log('activated');

        //parent halfbox - only get the first parent
        var parent = $(this).parent('.halfbox');
        parent.css('background', 'blue');

        //seems that you try to get the casetitle all the time
        //find the element with the class casetitle, which is inside the parent
        var ct = parent.find('.casetitle');

        //BOXOVERIDE - FOR WHEN THE URL CAN'T BE SET E.G. DASHBOARD

        if($(this).hasClass("allopen")){
            //change the html inside the h4
            ct.html('All Open Cases');
            caseGET = "&casetype=allopen";
        } else if($(this).hasClass("copen")){
            ct.html('My Created Cases (Open)');
            caseGET = "&casetype=copen";
        } else if($(this).hasClass("aopen")){
            ct.html('My Assigned Cases (Open)');
            caseGET = "&casetype=aopen";
        } else if($(this).hasClass("allclosed")){
            ct.html('All Closed Cases');
            caseGET = "&casetype=allclosed";
        } else if($(this).hasClass("cclosed")){
            ct.html('My Created Cases (Closed)');
            caseGET = "&casetype=cclosed";
        } else if($(this).hasClass("aclosed")){
            ct.html('My Assigned Cases (Closed)');
            caseGET = "&casetype=aclosed";
        } else if($(this).hasClass("apending")){
            ct.html('My Assigned Cases (Pending Close)');
            caseGET = "&casetype=apending";
        }
        console.log(caseGET);

        $(this).load("boxes/cases.php?boxtype=" + boxtype + caseGET + orgGET, function (){
            parent.find('.caseloader').hide();
        });
    });
};
```

Comment: fantastic @Greg I must give you extra kudos for figuring out that code :)